# Internal points and open intervals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a question in my book I've been having a hard time understanding how to solve.

Prove that in an open interval $(a,b)$ (including the possibility that $a = -\infty, b = \infty$) every point that belongs to it is an internal point.

I've tried choosing a value $c$ and adding an $\epsilon$ to it but I don't understand how to make sure that the $\epsilon$ is small enough to not go out of the interval bounds.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the distance from $c$ to the endpoints $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Did you mean $a=-\infty, b=\infty$? Because $(\infty,-\infty)$ makes no sense. Or more generally, also include the case where $a$ is finite and $b=\infty$, or $a=-\infty$ and $b$ is finite.

Comment: Hint: If $(a,b)$ is open, then $a<b$. Why is $a=b$ impossible?

Comment: yes sorry i wrote it wrong a=-∞ b=∞

Answer (score 0):

For $c\in (a,b)$

There are three cases:

**Case 1**: $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

choose $\epsilon=\min\{c-a,b-c\}$

**Case 2:** $a=-\infty$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$,

choose $\epsilon=b-c$

**Case 3:** $b=\infty$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$,

choose $\epsilon=c-a$

*So in any case you have that $c$ is an internal point of $(a,b)$*